# Add third party SSL(comodo positive wildcard) certificate on managed wordpress hosting by godaddy

Tags: wordpress, https

I have bought SSL certificate for my domain and all subdomian(*.abc.in). My main domain(abc.in) and sub-domain(blog.abc.in) are running on different server. I have installed certificate on my main server, where abc.in is hosted. and I am able to access https://abc.in now.

My blogs are on sub-domain blog.abc.in, and I want to make this also accessible from https://blog.abc.in(sub-domain). This sub-domain is linked with managed wordpress hosting provided by godaddy. I can't do it since i dont have access of its server. can someone tell me how to proceed fro the same. NOTE: I have my .crt, .key and .cer file with me.

EDIT:(I don't have comment permission so this is answer to comment.)
Godaddy support team are bunch of morons, they talk to me for more than half an hour, in which they kept me waiting for 20 minutes and after that they cut my call when i was on hold.

Comment: Can't godaddy support do it for you?

Comment: Getting cut off by GoDaddy isn't a reason to give up. Raise a support ticket or try calling again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have talked with GoDaddy team, and they told that they don't support 3rd party SSL for managed WordPress account. For installing SSL on your managed WordPress account you have to buy it from GoDaddy. I have moved my WordPress site to AWS. Then installed certificate on AWS server. Its working fine now.